# SQL - Calculate avg distance between cities calculated multiply times , cities in swapped columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table stores distance from city to city. Each city pair is measured multiple times by different people with different methods. The result is this:

```
(S-city, D-city, Distance)
(City A, City B, 30),
(City A, City B, 32),
(City B, City A, 29),
(City A, City C, 40),
(City C, City A, 41)
```

Write one SQL to display average distances of cities (no dupes in city pair, regardless of direction).

My Attempt:
I tried assigning the commute, either from A to B or B to as Route 1 and either A to C or C to A as route 2, as another route column, group by route column and find the average distance.

alter table google
 add route_direction int  null

update google 
 set route_direction = 
 case when (S_city='cityA' or S_city='cityB') and (D_city='cityA' or D_city='cityB')
 then 1
 else 2
 end

select route_direction, avg(distance)
 from google
 group by route_direction
 order by route_direction

WHich narrows down to 2 rows cityA-cityB and cityA-cityC, with average values.
These values are incorrect and moreover this code fails when there are multiple cities added.

Help?

Comment: please post your attempt as well.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products with different implementation of sql and other features. Therefore I removed the conflucting product tags. Pls add the one back you actually use. Moreover, pls do not just copy your home work task here. Pls post a reasonable attempt at solving it.

Comment: Also tried this, which gives a single row for cityA-cityB and cityA-cityC, but gives incorrect values:

 select t1.s_city, t2.d_city, avg(cast(t2.distance as float)) as average
 from google t1  inner join google t2
 on  t1.s_city=t2.s_city and t1.D_city <> t2.d_city
 group by t1.s_city, t2.d_city

Answer (score 1):

Use case to get distinct pairs:

```
select 
  (case when scity < dcity then scity else dcity end) city1, 
  (case when scity < dcity then dcity else scity end) city2,
  avg(cast(distance as float)) distance
from tablename 
group by
  (case when scity < dcity then scity else dcity end), 
  (case when scity < dcity then dcity else scity end)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fab2a2d87789b6e79c2a2c81cc2e8240)